# Checking ssh keys have passphrases

Tags: ssh, ssl, openssh, openssl

I have a bunch of users, who with SSH keys have access to accounts on other servers. Currently I have a script which collects up the ssh public keys and distributes them to the correct account on the correct servers.

What I want to do, is get that script to check that any given users ssh key has a passphrase before accepting the public key and distributing it.

I've tried a number of things, like using an `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` and then the problem comes when `ssh-add` gets asked for passphrase.

Is there a way to get something like `openssl` to check for passphrase, fail slightly with a return code of `1` if the key has a passphrase?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify whether the requirement is to _have_ a passphrase or _not_ to have it - and because of what reasons?

Comment: grawity: My requirement is to make sure users have set passphrases on their ssh keys, only keys with passphrases will get distributed to the other servers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a keyfile uses a passphrase it has "Proc-Type:" attribute set with the word "ENCRYPTED" appended.

So, you can determine if a keyfile uses passphrase by running it through `find` and `grep` to see if it has the string 'ENCRYPTED'.

```
# list keyfiles that USE a passphrase
HOMES=/home /mnt/nfs_home
find $HOMES -maxdepth 3 -type f -path '*/.ssh/id* -name "id_[dr]sa*" -exec grep -q "ENCRYPTED" {} \; -print
```

prints a list of files that *have* passphrases. Then you can match those against a list of all keyfiles to single out those that doesn't use a passphrase. A list of all keyfiles can be obtained e.g. by leaving the `-exec` parameter out, as follows:

```
# list all keyfiles
HOMES=/home /mnt/nfs_home
find $HOMES -maxdepth 3 -type f -path '*/.ssh/id* -name "id_[dr]sa*" -print
```

Comment: No longer possible with new SSH key format, the `Proc-Type` header is not written to the file, despite being encrypted.